# Visual Basic: determine size of array after spliting

Tags: arrays, vba, size

I have the following code

```
Sub Test()

Dim path As String
Dim pathSize As Integer

path = "1,45,6,131,13,71,35,141"
pathSize = Split(path, ",").Length

MsgBox (CStr(pathSize))

End Sub
```

I intended to determine the size of the path by splitting it with delimiter "," to an array containing 1, 45, 6, 131, 13, 71, 35, and 141 and measuring the size of the array. However, when I run this code, I get an error at line

```
pathSize = Split(path, ",").Length
```

with error "Object required". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
pathSize = Ubound(Split(path, ","))+1
```

Comment: Still not sure why my approach wouldn't work, but your solution gave me what I needed to get. Thank you.

Comment: @dylee the `.Length` property only applies to things like collection objects, it's not a valid property of an array type.

Comment: @dylee make sure you are not reading vb.net snippets and think they apply to vba - .Length would work as an extension on most enumerable objects in .net but vba does not have class extensions.